# How to send a URL string to a struct method using ajax

Tags: ajax, struts

I have a string which is basically a URL "http://www.demopage.com/sid=23&pop=wsa&jingle=yu

Now i want to send this url to the server using agax request. How can i do it.? Just send it as string and on the server side parse it.Create and object from it.Transfer the object back as ajax result and then save this object in some input field value.Is this possible..I know m talking crazy..

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to send as object. just send it with the url you have

```
$.ajax({url: 'ajax/test.html',
          success: function(data) {
             alert(data)  //data will be whatever you print or echo in your php file server side
            }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/